# Shared file system among pods

Tags: kubernetes, storage, nfs

We are running a cluster of x nodes.

Every node in the cluster pulls some files from remote storage. Unfortunately, the remote server is getting overloaded. So we are exploring a solution in which only a subset of the nodes pulls the files and are served to the remaining nodes (read-only - the other nodes do not need to write). Some subset of nodes can undergo maintenance often and can be taken offline.

I was experimenting with running NFS as a pod in a replica set with a service (fixed IP) for each of the NFS pods. If one node with the NFS-pod goes down, k8 will take care of bringing up an NFS-pod in another node with the same sticky IP.

But this new NFS would still need to remounted on the other nodes.

Any better solution for this storage problem?

Note that we would ideally not like to use remote storage since this adds extra latency.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider these options https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims

If you go with some locally managed it can be overhead for you to maintain, but you still have option which you can opt.